# Perform 2 searches in one query

Tags: c#, oledb

I need to get the id of the last record of the table and do a new search with it, I'm hours trying but could not get a result.
I basically need to put these queries together.
1st take the id and then update the information.
Thank you all.

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnClose.Enabled = false;
        btnOpen.Enabled = true;
        connection = new OleDbConnection(db);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            string query = "UPDATE Caixa SET Data_Fechamento = '" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Id_Caixa = " + idDay;

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Caixa fechado com sucesso!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing a reproducible code of the problem? What db backend and data access framework you are using?

Comment: I updated the question, posted the codes and in case my database use access and OLEDB